# Как убрать желтые границы textBox?

Tags: css

[image]

border-radius задал, но еще и такие желтые границы выходят. Как избавиться от них?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
outline-color: transparent;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ktjdM/

Answer (score 2):

или просто outline: none;